MSO home page returns "It was not possible to perform this tag search at this time due to an unexpected error" again
The MSO home page returns "It was not possible to perform this tag search at this time due to an unexpected error."

The page still appears to indicate if there is new activity since loading it, and can fetch posts with new activity.
This has been reported three times previously, with the first report stemming from 2017:

Again: It was not possible to perform this tag search at this time due to an unexpected error
It was not possible to perform this tag search at this time due to an unexpected error
Seeing "It was not possible to perform this tag search at this time due to an unexpected error" intermittently

None of these existing bug reports have a status tag attached to them.
This message appears to be generated server-side, so I don't think browser and OS details are relevant.
This bug appears to be at least 7 years old now.
How can we get this bug handled? Are there additional details we should provide when encountered, that are of help?

It is my understanding that this happens if you try to access the site in the middle of them doing a deploy. Which means it's extremely transient. Do you reliably reproduce this? Or you just see it once in a while, and then it immediately goes away?

I can't reliably reproduce this, could reproduce this for some time, but after posting it has just disappeared. If it's confirmed that's the case and there are no plans to address this, that'd make a good answer.

Oh, 20 minutes? I've never seen it for anywhere close to that long. I don't think it has even persisted for 2 minutes on any of the occasions that I've hit it. Anyway, I can't confirm that this is indeed related to a deploy; you'd need a developer in the employ of the company to do so. I only know what I manage to remember from ostensibly well-informed former CMs.

Related (same bug report): It was not possible to perform this tag search at this time due to an unexpected error and Again: It was not possible to perform this tag search at this time due to an unexpected error. Both don't have an answer. There is an answer in Seeing "It was not possible to perform this tag search at this time due to an unexpected error" intermittently but doesn't seem applicable.

He does link those in the post, @VLAZ. And, while Marc's answer to that specific instance does seem inapplicable, he does have this comment, which confirms my recollection that this happens during a deploy.

this comment by an SE employee at the time also hints at it happening during a deploy. With a comment above mentioning 15-30 minutes, so not a few seconds as mentioned by Marc but probably still infrequent and limited enough to not worry about if that's indeed the case.
